# Apache server gives 403 forbidden error on restart for phpmyadmin installation

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

On an ec2 amazon linux machine. I installed apache/mysql/phpmyadmin on intial instance creation. I'm able to view phpmyadmin no worries but when I restart the apache httpd daemon it  throws a

```
'You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/index.php on this server'
```

after I've logged in.

I've checked httpd.conf and have

```
'DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php'
```

its an index.php that it is accessing. Is there anything else to check (bit of a noob at this admin thing).
The fact its giving me a login screen means serving up content.

Regards,

sapatos

Comment: its now not even giving me the login screen, same error but at the phpmyadmin/ level not the index.php

Comment: have you found a solution yet?

Comment: sadly i did, and stuck the link on this page. however the page got deleted so it became useless so i deleted it. I also don't remember what the answer was sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I think I needed to add

`AllowOverride All`

to the `httpd.conf` inside the `<Directory ...>` entry describing my php code. Let me know if this doesn't help and I'll double check my apache configs.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and just entered:

```
setenforce 0
```

It instantly fixed it.